# Create a table with logs

Tags: php, sql, database, database-design, datatables

My quick question is that I have a table that records users relations: `userRelations(id, userID_1, userID_2, relationshipType, dateCreated)`. Now how do I create a log to see what was changed? Or by whom? Most of it is done php and then inserted into the table, but which columns must I have ?

EDIT: My difficulty was to understand the process of making a log, how to record, what to record, how many tables and such, I couldn't think clear enough to organize and say "This is what I need"

Comment: Unless the database you're using (which you didn't specify) has built-in logging features which meet your needs, you're going to have to record the information explicitly in your data.

Comment: I'm kinda just building the tables on paper because I don't want to redo it multiple times later. So suppose de DB doesn't have thst feature, can you give me a hint on how ?

Comment: If the DB doesn't have that feature, then you'd just have to record the data yourself.  I'm not sure what you mean by "how"?  You'd create tables and store data in them.  The application could write to the log table(s), or you could interact with the DB through stored procedures which write to the log table(s), or you could add triggers to the main table(s) which write to the log table(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new table that is updated each time this table is updated with the following headings

id,
userRelationsid (or shorten this if possible),
updatedby,
updatedrelationshipfrom (or shorten this if possible),
updatedrelationshipto (or shorten this if possible),
dateupdated,